# Mobile File Structure

Tags: android, mobile, file-structure

This is more of a general question. I am developing my first relatively large Android application, and I realize the file structure is probably not the "best practice" organization. I feel like I have one folder full with all of my Activities and Java classes, and it is getting a bit messy. Does anyone know what the best option is for making the project structure a bit cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these links very helpful. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770459/what-is-the-standard-way-to-organize-android-code-in-project), [Link 2](http://blog.smartlogic.io/2013/07/09/organizing-your-android-development-code-structure) and [Link 3](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Organizing-your-Source-Files).

Its a very debatable question. Some IDEs like Android Studio of google, Eclipse IDE for android automatically manage and keep ur source codes clean and compact.

Answer (score 2):

For organizing your source files take a look at some open source projects to get an idea about organizing your file structure. An example is the Google sample project [android-topeka](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/topeka).

This project groups the source code into sub-folders in the following structure:

```
/source
  /activity
  /adapter
  /fragment
  /helper
  /model
  /persistence
  /widget
```